# Eclipse Android Layout NullPointerException

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, nullpointerexception

When I try to view an Android layout file in Eclipse's Graphical Layout Editor, I get the error `"java.lang.NullPointerException: Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log"`, where the error log simply says `"main.xml: java.lang.NullPointerException."`
  It's only with this one particular project - I've moved this *main.xml* to another project, and the graphical editor works, and I've moved other (working) layouts into this project, and they stopped working.

I've tried the Android -> Fix Project Properties, but that didn't help, and I don't know which other settings would affect this.  Any advice on where to begin looking would be much appreciated!

Edit: Added code.  Also, this used to compile and run successfully, but I added the fileLabel TextView in the MainActivity.java file, and now it crashes at the `fileLabel.setText(timestamp)` line with a NullPointerException (LogCat posted below).

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Start" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Stop" />

</LinearLayout>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fileRecordingLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="File being recorded: "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fileLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
    android:text="Oct 22, 2013 12:50:30"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
@EActivity (R.layout.main)
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@ViewById
TextView lblWritingTo;
@ViewById
TextView fileLabel;

@Click
public void btnStart() {
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        String timestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()).toString().replace(' ', '_').replace(':', '-');
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).getAbsolutePath()+"/"+timestamp+".wav";

        lblWritingTo.setText("Writing to "+filepath);
        fileLabel.setText(timestamp);
    } else
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't access external storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

LogCat:

```
02-24 02:12:44.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1595): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 02:12:44.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1595): Process: com.camdroid.test, PID: 1595
02-24 02:12:44.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1595): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-24 02:12:44.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at com.camdroid.test.MainActivity.btnStart(MainActivity.java:52)
02-24 02:12:44.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at com.camdroid.test.MainActivity_$1.onClick(MainActivity_.java:47)
02-24 02:12:44.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
02-24 02:12:44.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
02-24 02:12:44.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-24 02:12:44.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-24 02:12:44.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-24 02:12:44.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
02-24 02:12:44.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 02:12:44.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-24 02:12:44.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-24 02:12:44.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-24 02:12:44.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: This happens before compilation - just when trying to view the file in the graphical editor.  Nothing appears in logcat.

Comment: It looks like AndroidAnnotations isn't recompiling the "back-end" code.  By adding lines like `fileLabel = (TextView)findView...` to MainActivity_.java (the AA file), the program works.  But I think the question now is, why doesn't AA update its file every time my file is updated, like it should?

Answer (score 2):

Do you clean the project ? 
project --> clean  (select your project)

Comment: Yep, tried cleaning the project and restarting Eclipse, the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project and build.

```
project --> clean
```

Restart eclipse once you clean the project.